# Why a truncated table for logic implication $(p\wedge q) \implies p$ verification?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The book *Discrete Mathematics* by Kenneth A. Ross says: "Let's verify the logic implication $(p\wedge q) \implies p$. For that, we need to consider only just the case when $p\wedge q$ is true; *i.e.*, both, $p$ and $q$, are true. This gives us the truncated table:"

[image: (pwedge q) rightarrow p]
"

Why the author considers that portion of the truth table? What reasoning I must understand to follow that validation technique?

*N.B.*: The same technique is applied to $(p \rightarrow q) \Rightarrow [(p \vee r) \rightarrow (q \vee r)]$:

[image: $(p \rightarrow q) \Rightarrow [(p \vee r) \rightarrow (q \vee r)]$]

Comment: It may help your Readers to cite which "book" and author your Question is based on.

Comment: Kenneth A. Ross - Discrete Mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that an implication $R\implies S$ is "automatically true" in cases where the hypothesis $R$ is *false*.  So the only interesting cases to check are those for which the hypothesis is *true*.

In this case the hypothesis is $p \wedge q$, so you can proceed just with analyzing what would be implied by that being true.

Answer (score 1):

The relation $p\rightarrow r$ is logically equivalent to $\neg p\vee r$. So for the case where $p$ is false, $\neg p$ is true and the outcome is then true. So the statement would be false only if $p$ is true and $r$ is false. Now replace this $p$ with $p\wedge q$  and $r$ by $p$ and you have a tautology.